# DjangoCMS aldryn-bootstrap3 link/button add a custom field (data-toggle)

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, django-cms, divio

i am using DjangoCMS with aldryn-bootstrap3 and i need extra attributes on the button/link element. Is it possible to add extra attributes to an element? I need data-* attributes

thank you!

btw: screenshot is fake :)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can install the package called [djangocms-attributes-field](https://github.com/divio/djangocms-attributes-field) to edit attributes (including data-*) via the front-end editor.

Comment: is it possible to use this plugin with aldryn_bootstrap3? 

i edit

https://github.com/aldryn/aldryn-bootstrap3/blob/master/aldryn_bootstrap3/models.py
```
lib/python2.7/site-packages/aldryn_bootstrap3/models.py
```
but I do not get it to run :( or is this the wrong place?

thanks!

Comment: I haven't checked, but you should be able to use it. Just install it by updating requirements.txt (or requirements.in). IIRC, if you install the django-filer CMS plugin, djangocms-attributes-field gets automatically installed.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my quick and dirty workaround:

i edit the template:

**./templates/aldryn_bootstrap3/plugins/button.html**
[aldryn_bootstrap3 button template](https://github.com/aldryn/aldryn-bootstrap3/blob/master/aldryn_bootstrap3/templates/aldryn_bootstrap3/plugins/button.html#L13)

```
    {% if 'modal' in instance.classes %}
       data-toggle="modal"
    {% endif %}
```

So if i edit the class "modal" data-toggle="modal" appears.

[image: add data-toggle with class modal]